# If I replace a flow orifice with a Coriolis flow meter of the same size do I need to worry about pressure drop with the new Coriolis meter?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, control-engineering, chemical-engineering, process-engineering, instrumentation

I have a 3 inch line with a 1.5 inch flow orifice. If I take out the flow orifice and put in a 1.5 inch coriolis meter will the pressure drop be the same or better with the new coriolis meter than with the flow orifice?

Comment: Well, does your meter come with a datasheet indicating any internal pressure losses?

Answer (score 1):

Usually flow orifices are very aggresive to the pressure. Everything you add has a pressure drop and doing calculations by hand of an equipment like that can be hell. So yes you should check the specs of the meter first.